Morphism from a minimal model to the canonical model
Assume that $(X,B)$ is a lc/klt pair where $B$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-divisor, and $(Y,B_Y)$ is a minimal model of $(X,B)$ such that $K_Y+B_Y$ is semi-ample, i.e. there is a contraction morphism $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ and an ample $\mathbb{R}$-Cartier divisor $H$ on $Z$ such that $K_Y+B_Y\sim_\mathbb{R}g^*H$.
Now assume furthermore that $K_Y+B_Y$ is big, can we deduce that the contraction $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ is birational? If so, how?

Yes, $g$ is birational. Suppose it were not: then $Y$ would be covered by curves on which $g^*H$, hence $K_Y+B_Y$, has degree $0$. But this is impossible for a big divisor.

@LazzaroCampeotti Are those curves you mentioned contracted by $g$? Also what is your definition of the degree of $K_Y+B_Y$?

Yes, I am talking about the curves contracted by $g$. I am assuming in this setup that $K_Y+B_Y$ is $\mathbb R$-Cartier, so it can be written as an $\mathbb R$-linear combination of Cartier divisors. Cartier divisors have well-defined degree on (aka intersection number with) any curve $C$, and this can be extended $\mathbb R$-linearly.

@LazzaroCampeotti So what you are saying is that, if $D$ is a big $\mathbb{R}$-divisor on $X$, then it must not be numerically trivial, since otherwise there exists an effective divisor $E$ s.t. $D-E$ is ample, and so for any curve $C\subset X$, we have $0<(D-E)\cdot C$, hence $C\subset SuppE$, which is a contradition. Is my interpretation correct?

I am saying something a bit stronger: not just that $D$ cannot be numerically trivial, rather it cannot even have intersection number zero with a single family of curves that covers $X$. The justification is exactly the same as what you wrote in your comment.

@LazzaroCampeotti Got it. Thanks!
